# How to give background image clickable for using js

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
<div class="feedback-header"><h3>FEEDBACK</h3></div>
```

css

```
.feedback-header
       { 
          border-bottom:1px solid #494c4d;
          padding:8px 20px 1px      20px;
          background:url(/_assets/img/common/btn-rt-arrow.png) 373px 25px no-repeat;
          position:absolute;
          width:381px
```

}

i have a arrow in the right side, i need to make the arrow click able for applying js

Comment: You can not make the background image or a part of it directly clickable. But the `div` or `.feedback-header` class can be clickable.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to add event on the CSS property.

You can only add event to the DOM elements. In your case you can add the click event to either class `.feedback-header` or specific element that have `class='feedback-header'`

Adding click to the all the elements that has `class='feedback-header'`

```
$(body).on('click', '.feedback-header', function(e){
  ....
});
```

The click will also be applied on the elements that are assigned that class in future by jQuery.

Answer (score 3):

As WDever pointed out, you cannot make part of a background-image clickable (unless you're using image maps), but what you can do is insert the background image as an `image` tag in the `feedback-header` div and make that clickable:

**HTML**

```
<div class="feedback-header">
    <img src="/_assets/img/common/btn-rt-arrow.png" />
    <h3>FEEDBACK</h3>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.feedback-header{ 
          border-bottom:1px solid #494c4d;
          padding:8px 20px 1px 20px;
          background:transparent none;
          position:absolute;
          width:381px;
}
.feedback-header img, h3 { display: inline; margin-right: 20px; }
```

**JS**

```
 $('div.feedback-header').on('click', 'img', function(){
        // Kill aliens and save the world here!
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make hook some trick to do it. like

```
<table style="background:url(/_assets/img/common/btn-rt-arrow.png)">
<tr>
   <td>
   Background arrow image' left side should be the same color as the element
   </td>
   <td id="arrow" onclick="FunctionToCall('this')">
     Your arrow sign should extend here.
   </td>
</tr>
</table>

function FunctionToCall() {
// write here
 }
```